# How to create a standalone web application with Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, blazor

I am new to Web development and Blazor. I would like to create a standalone web application using Blazor where the user would click on deployed files on local network and have the application start inside their web browser much like having a exe standalone for desktop applications. I have searched Windows documentation on Blazor but cant seem to find the answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably want to [wait for .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2536) which is bringing Blazor to the desktop as you envision. However, Telerik have an article about [wrapping it inside Electron](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/blazor-on-desktop) as well.

Comment: That would be awesome, thanks for sharing this!

Comment: You are looking for blazor pwa application. You can built it using . net 5.0 as well. Here is MS doc link for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: _"user would click on deployed files on local network and have the application start"_ is not a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building a blazor pwa application, this can be installed on desktop and it work like desktop application on windows or Mac OS. Here is the MS doc to create a sample pwa application.[link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

> Installation and app manifest
>
> When visiting an app created using the PWA template, users have the
> option of installing the app into their OS's start menu, dock, or home
> screen. The way this option is presented depends on the user's
> browser. When using desktop Chromium-based browsers, such as Edge or
> Chrome, an Add button appears within the URL bar. After the user
> selects the Add button, they receive a confirmation dialog:

[image]

> On iOS, visitors can install the PWA using Safari's Share button and its Add to Homescreen option. On Chrome for Android, users should select the Menu button in the upper-right corner, followed by Add to Home screen.

Once installed, the app appears in its own window without an address bar:

[image]

Comment: But you need to host the Blazor app on a web server for initial installtion of the PWA. Is it possible to deploy the PWA directly? (e.g. manually copying the files to the destination host)